# Using separate folders in powershell command

Tags: image, powershell, imagemagick, directory, subdirectory

I'm using Powershell and imagemagick to create a simple code to append images. I need to Powershell to be run from one folder, the input images to be take from a sub-folder, and the output images to be taken from a subfolder of that folder.

For example, the folder structure goes:

```
\image-converter\Append-images\Appended
```

So Powershell will be run from the "image-converter" folder, and will open with the directory:
PS

```
C:\Users\name\Downloads\image-converter>
```

The input images to be appended will be stored in the folder "Append-images", and the output images will be saved to the folder "Appended".

An example of the command I will be using is:

- `convert +append input.png input.png output.png`

So I would need to modify the command to take the input images from \Append-images and save the output images to \Append-images\Appended.

***P.S.*** I can't use the full `"C:\..."` path as this will be used by different people and the image-convert folder will be saved in different places. So I need the command to build on the `"PS C:\...\image-converter>"` path that Powershell will be run from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Get-Content -path "$scriptPath\Append-images\"
```

That should give you the location you need to browse the subsequent files.

Comment: But often these folders will be stored on network drives, so I can't use the userprofile as the default.

Additionally, these commands will be used by people with no experience of Powershell, so it needs to be a simple as possible (I'm creating an excel file that will compile the commands based on their input of the image names, so the solution needs to be simple enough for them to just copy and paste the resulting command).

Comment: Will the script be in the parent folder of the images?

Comment: Yes, the commands will always be run in the "image-converter" folder.

Comment: What about using $PSScriptRoot as your location variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variables to get the userprofile, and then your subdirectorys:

```
$env:userprofile
```

Will give you your `C:\Users\User1`

If you want to make the folders, do the following:

```
mkdir $env:userprofile\images
mkdir $env:userprofile\images\AppendImages
mkdir $env:userprofile\images\Output
```

And then work with those.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, I don't think that will work. As this will be used by different people and stored in different locations, the "image-converter" folder won't have the same directory. Often it will be stored on a network drive rather than the local C drive.

Comment: Well you know your environment better, but you can use `R:\Application\ImageConverter\` or whatever the path for the application on the network share, and then use the users path for exported images, temp storage etc. as you mentioned you couldn't use the hard path. You might also try cleaning up your question, as it is a little confusing what you want. Remember, this is a Q&A site.